# Создать экземпляр класса по данным в строке

Tags: java

Предположим у нас есть строка

```
Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=1.5, OS=Linux, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=2.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=19
```

И нам необходимо создать экземпляр класса Laptop с данными полями. Как и через что лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

## Решение №1: Пелёнки условных выражений

Этот вариант безопасен, надёжен и производителен. Но такой код тяжело поддерживать и его объёмы будут расти тем быстрее, чем больше будет возможных классов свойств у них.

```
public interface Device {
    // Какие-то общие для всех классов методы
}

class Laptop implements Device {
    private double batteryCapacity;
    private String os;
    private int memoryRom;
    private int systemMemory;
    private double cpu;
    private int displayInchs;

    // Конструкторы, аксессоры и прочее
}

abstract class DeviceFabric {
    private static final String PROPERTIES_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER = "=";

    public Device create(String properties) {
        return initialize(parseProperties(properties));
    }

    private static String[] trimAll(String[] items) {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
                     .map(String::trim)
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> parseProperties(String properties) {
        return Arrays.stream(properties.split(PROPERTIES_DELIMITER))
                     .map(s -> s.split(NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER))
                     .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
                     .map(DeviceFabric::trimAll)
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
    }

    protected abstract Device initialize(Map<String, String> properties);
}

class LaptopFabric extends DeviceFabric {
    @Override
    protected Device initialize(Map<String, String> properties) {
        Laptop laptop = new Laptop();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            String propertyName = entry.getKey();
            switch (entry.getKey()) {
                case "BATTERY_CAPACITY":
                    laptop.setBatteryCapacity(Double.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                    break;
                case "OS":
                    laptop.setOs(entry.getValue());
                    break;
                case "MEMORY_ROM":
                    laptop.setMemoryRom(Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                    break;
                case "SYSTEM_MEMORY":
                    laptop.setSystemMemory(Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                    break;
                case "CPU":
                    laptop.setCpu(Double.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                    break;
                case "DISPLAY_INCHS":
                    laptop.setDisplayInchs(Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.printf("Неизвестная характеристика оборудования - %s!%n", propertyName);
            }
        }
        return laptop;
    }
}

class InvalidFormatException extends Exception {
    public InvalidFormatException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

public class Example {
    private static final String DATA
      = "Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=1.5, OS=Linux, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=2.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=19";

    private static final String DELIMITER = ":";

    private static String[] split() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String[] parts = DATA.split(DELIMITER);
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            parts[0] = parts[0].trim();
            parts[1] = parts[1].trim();
            return parts;
        } else
            throw new InvalidFormatException("Неправильный формат входных данных!");
    }

    private static String getClassName() throws InvalidFormatException {
        return split()[0];
    }

    private static String getProperties() throws InvalidFormatException {
        return split()[1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DeviceFabric fabric = null;

            String className = getClassName();
            if ("Laptop".equals(className)) {
                fabric = new LaptopFabric();
            } else {
                System.err.printf("Неизвестный класс оборудования - %s!%n", className);
                return;
            }

            Device device = fabric.create(getProperties());
            System.out.println(device);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException exc) {
            System.err.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему пелёнки? И, наверное, стоит метод `split()` и все с ним связанные в `DeviceFabric` перенести. И разве это нормально, что `split()` вызывается каждый раз при запросе "`ClassName`" и "`Properties`"? Это же совершенно неэкономно! Это как бы `Example`, но смысл тогда делать в нём `Exception` и прочее?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия точно знал, что кто-нибудь это напишет :) Я старался соблюсти границу между простотой и подробностью, не скрыть суть за информационным шумом. Вероятно, можно было лучше, но я решил остановиться именно на этом варианте.

Answer (score 2):

## Решение №2: Рефлексия

Рефлексия - это чёрных ход в JVM, нивелирующий половину достоинств языка Java.  Рефлексивный код медленный и небезопасный. Применять рефлексию допустимо только при разработке инструментальных средств и фреймворков и даже при этом стоит стремиться сократить обращение к ней.

```
public interface Device {
    // Какие-то общие для всех классов методы
}

class Laptop implements Device {
    private Double batteryCapacity;
    private String os;
    private Integer memoryRom;
    private Integer systemMemory;
    private Double cpu;
    private Integer displayInchs;

    // Конструкторы, аксессоры и прочее
}

class InvalidFormatException extends Exception { }

public class Example {
    private static final String DATA
      = "Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=1.5, OS=Linux, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=2.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=19";
    
    private static final String DELIMITER = ":";
    private static final String PROPERTIES_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER = "=";
    private static final String WORDS_DELIMITER = "_";

    private static String[] split() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String[] parts = DATA.split(DELIMITER);
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            parts[0] = parts[0].trim();
            parts[1] = parts[1].trim();
            return parts;
        } else
            throw new InvalidFormatException();
    }

    private static String[] trimAll(String[] items) {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
                     .map(String::trim)
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static String getClassName() throws InvalidFormatException {
        return split()[0];
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getProperties() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String properties = split()[1];
        return Arrays.stream(properties.split(PROPERTIES_DELIMITER))
                     .map(s -> s.split(NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER))
                     .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
                     .map(Example::trimAll)
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
    }

    private static String capitalize(String str) {
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String snakeToCamel(String str) {
        if (str.contains(WORDS_DELIMITER))
            return Arrays.stream(str.split(WORDS_DELIMITER))
                         .map(Example::capitalize)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        else
            return capitalize(str);
    }
    
    private static String getSetterName(String propertyName) {
        return "set" + snakeToCamel(propertyName);
    }

    private static boolean isDouble(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    }

    private static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String className = getClassName();
            try {
                Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
                Object obj = cls.newInstance();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : getProperties().entrySet()) {
                    String setterName = getSetterName(entry.getKey());
                    try {
                        String value = entry.getValue();
                        Class<?> type = isInteger(value) ? Integer.class : isDouble(value) ? Double.class :
                          String.class;
                        Method setter = cls.getDeclaredMethod(setterName, type);
                        Method parser = null;
                        if (type != String.class)
                            parser = type.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);
                        try {
                            setter.invoke(obj, type != String.class ? parser.invoke(null, value) : value);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException exc) {
                        exc.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(obj);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
                System.err.printf("Класс %s не найден!", className);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException exc) {
            System.err.println("Неправильный формат входных данных!");
        }
    }
}
```

Для простоты я сделал все поля `Laptop` ссылочных типов, но это необязательно.

Comment: Для проверки на `double` лучше использовать `[-+]?\d+(.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+)?`, а для `int` - `[-+]?\d+`. А вместо `trimAll()`, наверное, лучше написать так: `.collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0].trim(), a -> a[1].trim()))`.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия про регуляркам согласен, про `trimAll` нет. Во-первых, идиоматичнее обработку данных выполнять в конвейерных операциях, а не терминальных. Во-вторых, нужно стремиться к максимальной декомпозиции и конкретности операции, выполнение `trim` в коллекторе - это дополнительная обязанность, не относящаяся к процессу сборки.

Comment: Но ведь это позволяет экономить ресурсы.

Comment: Как писал один умный человек про абстракции и паттерны: "Это замедлит ваши программы, но ускорит ваших программистов". Очень важно найти грань между экономией на спичках и написанием _чистого кода_.

Answer (score 2):

## Решение №3: Кодогенерация с помощью манипуляции байткодом

Ещё более хакерский вариант, чем рефлексия, с ещё более узким диапазоном оправданного применения. Зато писать класс `Laptop` больше не нужно, он будет сгенерирован на лету.

```
public interface Device {
    // Какие-то общие для всех классов методы
}

class InvalidFormatException extends Exception { }

class DynamicClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public Class<?> defineClass(String name, byte[] b) {
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }
}

class DeviceFabric {
    private static final String WORDS_DELIMITER = "_";

    private static String capitalize(String str) {
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String snakeToCamel(String str) {
        if (str.contains(WORDS_DELIMITER))
            return Arrays.stream(str.split(WORDS_DELIMITER))
                         .map(DeviceFabric::capitalize)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        else
            return str.toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String getFieldName(String propertyName) {
        String str = snakeToCamel(propertyName);
        return str.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + str.substring(1);
    }

    private static boolean isDouble(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    }

    private static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+");
    }

    private static String getTypeName(Class<?> cls) {
        return cls.getName().replace(".", "/");
    }
    
    private static String getTypeDescriptor(Class<?> cls) {
        return "L" + getTypeName(cls) + ";";
    }
    
    private static byte[] generateBytecode(String className, Map<String, String> properties) {
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

        // Объявление генерируемого класса
        cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_8, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, className, null, "java/lang/Object", new String[] { "Device" });

        // Конструктор генерируемого класса
        MethodVisitor con = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
        con.visitCode();
        con.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
        con.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V", false);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = getFieldName(entry.getKey());
            String value = entry.getValue();
            Class<?> type = isInteger(value) ? Integer.class : isDouble(value) ? Double.class : String.class;

            // Объявление поля класса
            cw.visitField(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, fieldName, getTypeDescriptor(type), null, null);

            // Установка значения поля в конструкторе
            con.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            con.visitLdcInsn(type == Double.class ? Double.valueOf(value) : type == Integer.class
              ? Integer.valueOf(value) : value);
            if (type != String.class) {
                con.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, getTypeName(type), "valueOf",
                  (type == Double.class ? "(D)" : "(I)") + getTypeDescriptor(type), false);
            }
            con.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.PUTFIELD, className, fieldName, getTypeDescriptor(type));
        }
        con.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
        con.visitMaxs(3, 1);

        // Метод toString генерируемого класса
        MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", null, null);
        mv.visitCode();
        mv.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "java/lang/StringBuilder");
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "<init>", "()V", false);
        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Object", "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;", false);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Class", "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;", false);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append",
          "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
        mv.visitLdcInsn("(");
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", 
          "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = properties.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
            String fieldName = getFieldName(entry.getKey());
            String value = entry.getValue();
            Class<?> type = isInteger(value) ? Integer.class : isDouble(value) ? Double.class : String.class;

            mv.visitLdcInsn(fieldName + "=");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", 
              "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
            mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETFIELD, className, fieldName, getTypeDescriptor(type));
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", 
              "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                mv.visitLdcInsn(", ");
                mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", 
                  "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
            }
        }

        mv.visitLdcInsn(")");
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;",
          false);
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ARETURN);
        mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);

        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Device createDevice(String className, Map<String, String> properties)
      throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        DynamicClassLoader loader = new DynamicClassLoader();
        Class<?> cls = loader.defineClass(className, generateBytecode(className, properties));
        return (Device) cls.newInstance();
    }
}

public class Example {
    private static final String DATA
      = "Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=1.5, OS=Linux, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=2.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=19";
    
    private static final String DELIMITER = ":";
    private static final String PROPERTIES_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER = "=";

    private static String[] split() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String[] parts = DATA.split(DELIMITER);
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            parts[0] = parts[0].trim();
            parts[1] = parts[1].trim();
            return parts;
        } else
            throw new InvalidFormatException();    
    }

    private static String[] trimAll(String[] items) {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
                     .map(String::trim)
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static String getClassName() throws InvalidFormatException {
        return split()[0];
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getProperties() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String properties = split()[1];
        return Arrays.stream(properties.split(PROPERTIES_DELIMITER))
                     .map(s -> s.split(NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER))
                     .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
                     .map(Example::trimAll)
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1], (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String className = getClassName();
            Map<String, String> properties = getProperties();

            try {
                Device device = DeviceFabric.createDevice(className, properties);
                System.out.println(device);
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException exc) {
            System.err.println("Неправильный формат входных данных!");
        }
    }
}
```

Для сокращения объёма кода я сделал все поля генерируемого класса публичными, но это не обязательно, можно сделать их приватными и сгенерировать для них аксессоры.

Подобный подход использует, например, фреймворк Spring. Для манипуляции байткодом существует достаточно обширный набор библиотек (bcel, cglib, asm, javassist, bytebuddy) и все они хорошо документированы. Я в этом примере использовал библиотеку [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/).

Answer (score 2):

## Решение №4: Кодогенерация с помощью API компилятора

Overkill! На лету генерируется java-код и компилируется прямо в рантайме. Медленнее, чем вариант с генерацией байткода, но безопаснее.

```
public interface Device {
    // Какие-то общие для всех классов методы
}

class InvalidFormatException extends Exception { }

class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private final String code;

    public JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        return code;
    }
}

class DeviceFabric {
    private static final String WORDS_DELIMITER = "_";
    private static final String KV_DELIMITER = "=";
    private static final String PREFIX = "(";
    private static final String SUFFIX = ")";
    private static final String INFIX = ", ";

    private static final ClassLoader classLoader = ToolProvider.getSystemToolClassLoader();
    private static final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    private static String capitalize(String str) {
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String snakeToCamel(String str) {
        if (str.contains(WORDS_DELIMITER))
            return Arrays.stream(str.split(WORDS_DELIMITER))
                         .map(DeviceFabric::capitalize)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
        else
            return str.toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String getFieldName(String propertyName) {
        String str = snakeToCamel(propertyName);
        return str.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + str.substring(1);
    }

    private static boolean isDouble(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
    }

    private static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+");
    }

    private static String getTypeName(Class<?> cls) {
        return cls.getName().replace(".", "/");
    }
    
    private static String getTypeDescriptor(Class<?> cls) {
        return "L" + getTypeName(cls) + ";";
    }
    
    private static String generateSource(String className, Map<String, String> properties) {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        JavacFileManager.preRegister(ctx);
        TreeMaker treeMaker = TreeMaker.instance(ctx);
        JavacElements elements = JavacElements.instance(ctx);

        JCTree.JCModifiers modifiers = treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC);

        // Определения полей и тела конструктора
        ListBuffer<JCTree> fields = new ListBuffer<>();
        ListBuffer<JCTree.JCStatement> assignments = new ListBuffer<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            String fieldName = getFieldName(entry.getKey());
            String value = entry.getValue();
            String type = isInteger(value) ? "Integer" : isDouble(value) ? "Double" : "String";

            fields.append(treeMaker.VarDef(modifiers, elements.getName(fieldName),
              treeMaker.Ident(elements.getName(type)), null));

            assignments.append(treeMaker.Exec(
                treeMaker.Assign(
                    treeMaker.Select(
                        treeMaker.Ident(
                            elements.getName("this")
                        ),
                        elements.getName(fieldName)
                    ),
                    treeMaker.Literal(type == "Integer" ? Integer.valueOf(value) : type == "Double"
                      ? Double.valueOf(value) : value)
                )
            ));
        }

        // Определение конструктора
        JCTree.JCMethodDecl constructor = treeMaker.MethodDef(
            modifiers,
            elements.getName(className),
            null,
            List.<JCTree.JCTypeParameter>nil(),
            List.<JCTree.JCVariableDecl>nil(),
            List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil(),
            treeMaker.Block(0, assignments.toList()),
            null
        );

        // Тело метода toString
        JCTree.JCExpression expression = treeMaker.Literal(className + PREFIX);
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = properties.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
            String fieldName = getFieldName(entry.getKey());
            String value = entry.getValue();

            JCTree.JCExpression fieldAccess = treeMaker.Select(
                treeMaker.Ident(
                    elements.getName("this")
                ),
                elements.getName(fieldName)
            );

            expression = treeMaker.Binary(JCTree.Tag.PLUS, expression, treeMaker.Literal(fieldName + KV_DELIMITER));
            expression = treeMaker.Binary(JCTree.Tag.PLUS, expression, fieldAccess);

            if (it.hasNext()) {
                expression = treeMaker.Binary(JCTree.Tag.PLUS, expression, treeMaker.Literal(INFIX));
            }
        }
        expression = treeMaker.Binary(JCTree.Tag.PLUS, expression, treeMaker.Literal(SUFFIX));
        JCTree.JCBlock methodBody = treeMaker.Block(0, List.of(treeMaker.Return(expression)));

        // Определение toString
        JCTree.JCMethodDecl method = treeMaker.MethodDef(
            modifiers,
            elements.getName("toString"),
            treeMaker.Ident(elements.getName("String")),
            List.<JCTree.JCTypeParameter>nil(),
            List.<JCTree.JCVariableDecl>nil(),
            List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil(),
            methodBody,
            null
        );

        // Определение генерируемого класса
        JCTree.JCClassDecl tree = treeMaker.ClassDef(
            modifiers,
            elements.getName(className),
            List.<JCTree.JCTypeParameter>nil(),
            null,
            List.of(treeMaker.Ident(elements.getName("Device"))),
            fields.toList().append(constructor).append(method)
        );

        return tree.toString();
    }

    private static void compile(Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits) {
        CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, compilationUnits);
        task.call();    
    }

    public static Device createDevice(String className, Map<String, String> properties)
      throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        java.util.List<JavaFileObject> sources = new ArrayList<>();
        sources.add(new JavaSourceFromString(className, generateSource(className, properties)));
        compile(sources);

        Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass(className);
        return (Device) cls.newInstance();
    }
}

public class Example {
    private static final String DATA
      = "Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=1.5, OS=Linux, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=2.2, DISPLAY_INCHS=19";
    
    private static final String DELIMITER = ":";
    private static final String PROPERTIES_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER = "=";

    private static String[] split() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String[] parts = DATA.split(DELIMITER);
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            parts[0] = parts[0].trim();
            parts[1] = parts[1].trim();
            return parts;
        } else
            throw new InvalidFormatException();    
    }

    private static String[] trimAll(String[] items) {
        return Arrays.stream(items)
                     .map(String::trim)
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    private static String getClassName() throws InvalidFormatException {
        return split()[0];
    }

    private static Map<String, String> getProperties() throws InvalidFormatException {
        String properties = split()[1];
        return Arrays.stream(properties.split(PROPERTIES_DELIMITER))
                     .map(s -> s.split(NAME_VALUE_DELIMITER))
                     .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
                     .map(Example::trimAll)
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1], (a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String className = getClassName();
            Map<String, String> properties = getProperties();

            try {
                Device device = DeviceFabric.createDevice(className, properties);
                System.out.println(device);
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException exc) {
            System.err.println("Неправильный формат входных данных!");
        }
    }
}
```

Похожий способ использует популярная библиотека Lombok. Только кодогенарация происходит не совсем в рантайме, а на этапе обработки компилятором аннотаций.

Я в этом примере использовал [Compiler API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=199), входящий в Open JDK и производные от него.

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант...

```java
Laptop laptop = new Laptop();
laptop.setBatteryCapacity(1.5);
laptop.setOS("Linus");
laptop.setMemory(8000);
laptop.setSystemMemory(1000);
laptop.setCpu(2.2);
laptop.setDisplayInches(19);

//Посмотреть данные в созданном объектt
System.out.println(laptop.toString());
```

```java
public class Laptop {
    private double batteryCapacity;
    private String OS;
    private int memory;
    private int systemMemory;
    private double cpu;
    private int displayInches;

    public double getBatteryCapacity() {
        return batteryCapacity;
    }

    public void setBatteryCapacity(double batteryCapacity) {
        this.batteryCapacity = batteryCapacity;
    }

    public String getOS() {
        return OS;
    }

    public void setOS(String OS) {
        this.OS = OS;
    }

    public int getMemory() {
        return memory;
    }

    public void setMemory(int memory) {
        this.memory = memory;
    }

    public int getSystemMemory() {
        return systemMemory;
    }

    public void setSystemMemory(int systemMemory) {
        this.systemMemory = systemMemory;
    }

    public double getCpu() {
        return cpu;
    }

    public void setCpu(double cpu) {
        this.cpu = cpu;
    }

    public int getDisplayInches() {
        return displayInches;
    }

    public void setDisplayInches(int displayInches) {
        this.displayInches = displayInches;
    }
}
```

Comment: Суть то в том, чтобы преобразовать строку в поля класса.