# Программное создание класса

Tags: java

Каким образом можно программно создать новый java класс? И можно ли вообще?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону динамических классов.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересно почитать ответы 3 и 4 на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1000138/204271).

Answer (score 0):

У класса Class нет публичных конструкторов. Class - это generic тип. Методы Class предназначены для получения информации о классе (объекте типа Class). Эти методы нужны для reflection. С помощью reflection вы можете создавать объекты, которые принадлежат этому классу, и при этом заранее класс объекта вы можете не знать.

Почитайте подробнее про: Java Reflection API, и для создания Class на лету, рекомендую ознакомиться с  Spring Framework  и Java EE, там есть инструменты для создания и изменения классов на лету в коде.